# Use xcode refactoring with a objective-c++ file in the project

Tags: xcode4, refactoring, objective-c++, zxing

I just started using the [ZXing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/zxing/&ei=PN3bTtiUCdPbiAKH5I2-BA&usg=AFQjCNGFH2ouoZW2Ox0eLH7K_cJof-5zVQ&sig2=KRDzbnUjTc8ukPALeo3nOQ) SDK in my iPhone project. This requires that include it be renamed to .mm files (objective-c++).

The problem is that because of one file in my project xcode refactoring has been disabled for the entire thing.

Is there a work around to this issue? A way to refactor for everything except that file or a better way to include things? Possibly by making a static lib of third party code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recreate the problem you're having by adding a C++ file to a Cocoa project. I was able to enable the refactoring menu items by selecting a different file in the project navigator and selecting some text. If that doesn't work, you could remove the one file from the project, do the refactoring, and add the file back to the project.